# Implement a pixel grid using AVL-trees

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I need to implement a grid of pixels triples of type `(x_coord, y_coord, color)`, using some number of AVL-trees. 
Particularly, I should be able to execute this functions:

- `nextInRow(x,y)`
- `nextInCol(x,y)`
- `readColor(x,y)`

with complexity **O(log n)**.

I am completely lost and have no idea how to do it efficiently. 
Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One smart way to implement this using AVL-trees is to have two separate AVL-trees, one that is sorted by x-coordinate and the other that is sorted by y-coordinate. So you will use the first one to implement `nextInRow(x,y)` and the second one for `nextInCol(x,y)`.

Mind that you should sync your changes for one tree with another tree.